# qyoto on windows

Tags: .net, windows, qt, compilation, qyoto

I'm trying to install or compile qyoto on windows, but without any success :(
I've downloaded source codes from [official qyoto web site](http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Languages/Qyoto).
But I don't know how can I run examples, how can I compile qyoto?
I always  program on Windows and I've never handled with Unix.

I tried to find some kind of tutorial how to compile qyoto code or qyoto itself.

Please, help me!
Sorry for my Bad English.

I will be grateful to any advice

Answer (score 0):

You are better using the windows package manager called `emerge` written by the KDE Windows contributors. Otherwise, you may have tricky issues.

Here you can find an introduction for it:

Project: http://windows.kde.org/

Package manager: http://techbase.kde.org/Getting_Started/Build/Windows/emerge

You can go and build yourself if you wanna go down that way. Basically, you need to get the dependencies built, and then create a shadow build folder. Go into that, and run cmake from there against the main CMakeLists.txt file with `cmake ..`